# How to list individual students grades...?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, awt

Using multi-dimensional arrays is a first for me, so my understanding of some of the aspects that come with these arrays are a bit...vague. Now for a quick review of what this program will be used for once completed...

It collects the inputted students names and four corresponding test scores. You can find the average of the school with it and now I'm attempting to find average of each individual student.

```
public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {

int [][] aryStudent = new int [15][4]; // [15] being max students [4] being # of test scores
String[] studentNames = new String[15]; 
int numOfStudents = 0; //student names start from 0...

int marks = 0;

int test1;
int test2;
int test3;
int test4;

public StudentGradesView(SingleFrameApplication app) {

//unimportant...for GUI

}                                          

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

//this is fine...just collects the names and test scores and ists them in studentListField...

```
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int x=0; x <= numOfStudents && x<15; x++) {
        sb.append(firstNameField.getText() + " " + lastNameField.getText());
        for (int y=0; y < 4; y++) {
            sb.append(" " + aryStudent[x][y]);
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    studentListField.setText(sb.toString());
    numOfStudents ++;
}                                         

private void classAverageButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

//finds school average....its fine

```
    for(int x = 0; x < numOfStudents && x<15; x++) {
        averageField.setText("The class average is " + (aryStudent[x][0] + aryStudent[x][1] + aryStudent[x][2] + aryStudent[x][3])/4 + "%");
    }

}                                                  

private void studentAverageButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

But then! This...I thought this would list the students averages individually, but it only inputs one student at a time, which is a problem...All it needs to do is list similar to this...

John Smith 78
Jane Doe 80
etc etc

```
     for (int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++) {
         for (int y = 0; y < marks; y++) {
             averageField.setText("Student" + (aryStudent[y][0] + aryStudent[y][1] + aryStudent[y][2] + aryStudent[y][3])/4);
         }
    }
     marks++;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `averageField`?

Answer (score 0):

what is exactly the variable `marks` in the last piece of code? it is outside the loop so it does not actually do anything. What I expect your code to do if for instance there are 4 students and marks is 3 would be the following
    (i=0 y=0),  StudentA 
    (i=0 y=1), StudentB 
    (i=0 y=2), StudentC

```
(i=1 y=0),  StudentA <AVG>
(i=1 y=1), StudentB <AVG>
(i=1 y=2), StudentC <AVG>

(i=2 y=0),  StudentA <AVG>
(i=2 y=1), StudentB <AVG>
(i=2 y=2), StudentC <AVG> 

....
```

Try to print your results in text mode first (without any GUI). When it will work there you can move to GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Your indices does not appear to be correct. You're using `y`, which is the mark index as the student index, and `i` is unused. Also, the way you did it, you don't need 2 loops.

This problem might've been avoided if you named `i` `s` for student and `y` `m` for mark.

Also, by using `setText`, you're replacing the text, not adding to it. Assuming you're using a `JTextArea`, you should use `append` instead.

It should look like:

```
 averageField.setText(""); // clear
 for (int s = 0; s < numOfStudents; s++)
    averageField.append(studentNames[s] + " - " + (aryStudent[s][0] +
       aryStudent[s][1] + aryStudent[s][2] + aryStudent[s][3])/4 + "\n");
```

A more generic way:

```
 averageField.setText(""); // clear
 for (int s = 0; s < numOfStudents; s++)
 {
    int average = 0;
    for (int m = 0; m < marks; m++)
       average += aryStudent[s][m];
    average /= 4;
    averageField.append(studentNames[s] + " - " + average + "\n");
 }
```

Note that you're class average also appears to be incorrect. It currently only shows the last student's average (`setText` also replaces as you go).

Something like this should work:

```
int average = 0;
for (int s = 0; s < numOfStudents; s++)
   for (int m = 0; m < marks; m++)
      average += aryStudent[s][m];
average /= numOfStudents * marks;
averageField.setText("The class average is " + average + "%");
```

Also, wouldn't (or shouldn't) `numOfStudents` be limited to `15`, why are you checking for both values?